# Connecting to multiple database at run time in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have rails application which requires many database(currently 4,5). I am a newbie in rails, and not getting how to connect to database in real time. I have seen ror docs, we can use *establish_connection* at model level to connect to db. I am using Postgresql db.

for example, we have 3 users, and 3 database. At run time when user 1 selects an option 'a', then the user will be connected to database A, user 2 selects option 'b', then the  user will be connected to database B, when user 3 selects option 'a', the the application would use the existing connection which has already been established when user 1.

note that user will be connected to database for entire life cycle once he is connected to particular database.

I know i have not described the problem perfectly but i hope i was able to convey my problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Checkout https://prathamesh.tech/2019/08/13/rails-6-multi-database-part-two where there is a hint how you can achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks @AmitPatel for quick response, i have gone through the article. the example was suggesting to write database name which is fixed. but in our situation, depending upon user selection(from UI) the corresponding db will be connected. also it's not good practice to write establish_connection under every model method. hope you got what my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rails really isn't set up to do this.  Instead of fighting rails, maybe just do the really really easy thing:

Run *N* instances of your application and send the user to the appropraite one once they have decided which they want.

It's not glamorous or an interesting technical challenge - but it's dead simple and should do the job.